# ESP32: Compile errors when using IRAM_ATTR

Tags: c++, embedded

I am sure I am doing something really stupid, but here goes..
I get a compile error when I use IRAM_ATTR for my ISR. I am compiling for ESP32.

Here is the definition of the ISR

```
void 
IRAM_ATTR
detectsBlockOccupancy() {
    ....
    ISR code..
    ...
}
```

And here is the first usage:

```
void setup() {

// Set Sensor pin as interrupt, assign interrupt function and set RISING mode
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(BDInterruptPin), detectsBlockOccupancy, RISING);
...
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

> In function 'void setup()': Node0:226:90: error: invalid conversion
> from 'int (*)()' to 'void (*)()' [-fpermissive]
> attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(BDInterruptPin), detectsBlockOccupancy, RISING);
> ^ In file included from
> C:\Users\vibhas\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\cores\esp32/esp32-hal.h:53:0,
> from C:\Users\vibhas\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:35,
> from sketch\Node0.ino.cpp:1: C:\Users\vibhas\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\cores\esp32/esp32-hal-gpio.h:81:6:
> note:   initializing argument 2 of 'void attachInterrupt(uint8_t, void
> (*)(), int)'  void attachInterrupt(uint8_t pin, void (*)(void), int
> mode);
> ^

---

If I remove the IRAM_ATTR then it compiles fine. It seems to think that I am trying to pass a different type of function pointer.
What could I be doing wrong ?

Thanks
vibhas

Comment: Find where IRAM_ATTR is defined and I think you will find your problem.